# Incrementing across a changeable distance 0-1 keeping time equal

Tags: c#, math, distance, increment

I'm unable to think through this one I think it's one of those moments where the answer is really simple but I'm too close to the problem to see the solution.

I have a distance that's changeable and an object that has to traverse this distance in the same time regardless of length.

The start of the distance is valued as 0 and the end of the distance is valued as 1.

Obviously the incrementation will be smaller the larger the length to keep the times equal.

What formula could I use to calculate the 0-1 incrementation but keep the time taken equal.

I know it seems overly complicated way to increment but it's part of the third party plugin I've been given.

I'm coding in C#.

Thanks.

[EDIT]
Sorry I wasn't very clear.
For incrementation the start point is always 0 and the end point is always 1.
So the object can move += 0.5 for example.
so when the length increase from say 30 to 65 it should take longer to increment from 0 to 1.

Comment: Won't the incrementation be _bigger_ the larger the length?

Comment: @Tudor No, sorry I wasn't very clear, incrementation is always from 0 to 1. So the longer the length the longer it should take to get from 0 to 1 so the incrementation should be less. See my edit. Let me know if I'm still being unclear.

Comment: @Servy Sorry, that isn't useable in this instance.

Comment: @Dave It most certainly is usable.  Your incrementation is the speed.  You are moving that distance over a fixed period of time.  The total distance, in this case, is 1 (from 0 to 1).  The time is the number of ticks (number of times you increment your current position).  Therefore `speed = distance / time` becomes `sizeOfIncrement = 1 / numTicks`

Comment: @Servy Forgive me if I'm wrong but won't that give me the same incrementation every time? How does this factor in changes in length?

Comment: @Dave You haven't stated in what way 'length' is relevant.  How should it matter?  According to you you are incrementing from 0 to 1 over a constant period of time.  The movement per iteration is entirely dependent on that alone.  For 'length' to affect this it would need to either determine the distance over which you are incrementing (according to you it's not) or change the time it takes to go from 0 to 1 (which you say is constant).

Comment: Oh I see. It's a scroll list where a _position_ on the scroll list ranges between 0 and 1. The total length of the elements in the scroll list is changeable. So where with 10 elements in the scroll list incrementing the scroll position at a speed of 0.2 might seem ok, incrementing at that speed with 100 elements in the scroll list would cause elements to whiz buy at lightning speed. What I'm looking for is an equation that provides an incrementation between 0 and 1 that is constant over all element lengths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are looking for a way to have a number `x` in the range [`0`,`1`] that maps to some `y` in some arbitrary range [`min`,`max`], and are looking for the increment value a such that if `x` -> `y` then `x` + `a` -> `y` + `b` for some constant `b`?  If I have understood your question correctly, then your `a` value should be:

`a = b / (max - min)` note: make sure to format this correctly for C#, especially be sure to cast and that sort of thing.

This is basically saying that `a` should be the fraction of the range that `a` spans, that if `b` is half the range from `min` to `max`, then `a` should be 0.5, and if `b` spans one fifth the range, `a` should be 0.2.

Comment: Thanks that's pretty much what I was looking for